# Как обратится к элементам динамического массива из другой функции того же класса

Tags: c++, qt

Есть у меня класс Group_Zub, и нужно мне в другом классе массив данных элементов. Пока 6, потом может быть 10-20.
Поэтому создаю динамически массив в конструкторе, а потом, когда пытаюсь обратится к его элементам в другой функции класса...  "Что? Не знаю такого, иди отсюда"

```
//dialog.h
Group_Zub **groupZub;
int countGroup;

//dialog.cpp
//конструктор
countGroup = 6;
groupZub = new Group_Zub*[countGroup];

//слот нажатия кнопки
if (ui->groupZub[1]->isVisible())
   stages++;
```

ошибка во время компиляции: 'class Ui::Dialog' has no member named 'groupZub'
     if (ui->groupZub[1]->isVisible())
             ^
Вопрос: как получить доступ к этим элементам? Менять их состояния видимости, получать информацию от них...

Upd: пример...
Ну пусть будет вместо groupZub любой потомок QWidget. Например, QLabel
Тогда,

```
//dialog.h

namespace Ui {
class Dialog2;
}

class Dialog2 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QLabel**groupZub;
    int countGroup;
}

//dialog.cpp
//конструктор
Dialog2::Dialog2(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog2)
{
countGroup = 6;
groupZub = new QLabel*[countGroup];  
}

//слот нажатия кнопки
void Dialog2::on_pushButtonCount_clicked()
{    
if (ui->groupZub[1]->isVisible())
       stages++;
}
```

Или вам файл проекта дать?

Comment: Ошибка компиляции или при работе программы? Какая ошибка выдается?

Comment: "Что? Не знаю такого, иди отсюда" -  это кто так ругается, компилятор? Во техника куда ушла!  Гетеры и сетеры добавте.

Comment: @Honlon  Приведите минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему, который можно запустить на компиляцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что ui указывает не ваш класс, а на код сгенерированный UIC-ом из *.ui файла, уберите ui->, при обращении к groupZub

Comment: Уиии~ Огромное спасибо) Так и знала что косяк в чём-то простом) Подумала, что логично обращаться через форму, раз я его туда уже добавила :)